# Does declaring a private string as a reference make a difference?

Tags: c++, reference

While i was reading my c++ book and programming some of the examples, a question came to my mind.

```
...
private:
    const string someString;

public:
    MyClass(const string& someString) : someString(someString) {}
    const string& getSomeString() const { return someString; }
...
```

Does declaring someString as a reference actually make a difference?

```
...
private:
    const string& someString;

public:
    MyClass(const string& someString) : someString(someString) {}
    const string& getSomeString() const { return someString; }
...
```

If so, what are the advantages/disadvantages or use cases (since both examples compile fine)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The latter will easily lead to dangling references as it just points to some object not controlled by your class. So I would avoid that. (As always, unless you have a good reason.)

Also a notable difference: In the second case, the string in your class "will change" if the string used to construct it does, as you are only referencing it. This would not happen in the first case as you own your own copy of the string.

Answer (score 3):

If you want a string of your own, don't store a reference to somebody else's string.

In the second case, the lifetime of the string you're storing a reference to must exceed that of the object you're storing it in.

For example,

```
 MyClass instance("bad");
```

would leave a dangling reference in the member.

You also have the less fatal but confusing spooky action at a distance:

```
std::string s = "Hello";
MyClass instance(s);
s = "World";
std::cout << instance.getSomeString(); // Prints 'World'
```

Reference members are very rarely a good solution, in my experience.

Answer (score 1):

The string referenced in the constructor comes from outside the class. The reference member is only valid as long as the original string is valid. Consider this example:

```
MyClass *p;
{
    string temp = "hello";
    p = new MyClass(temp);
}
cout << p->getSomeString(); // reference to destroyed object
```

This code is wrong because the string `temp` which is referred to in the class no longer exists.

The problem can manifest more subtly.

```
const char *text = "Hello";
MyClass c(text);
cout << c.getSomeString(); // reference to destroyed object
```

This code is also wrong because the temporary `std::string` object created for the constructor call no longer exists by the time of the next line.

Answer (score 1):

If you declare `someString` as a `const string` it will contain that value that is passed to it in the constructor.

However, with `someString` being a `const string&`, it holds the address of a string which is stored somewhere outside of the class, which the class can't guarantee will still exist at any point in the future, so you should avoid this one.

Answer (score 0):

If `someString` should not be an observer, then by storing a reference you're implying the wrong semantics. I would avoid that.

Otoh, if it should be an observer then you obviously do have to store a reference.

Comment: What do you mean by "observer"?

Comment: A reference that only reads. If the referenced object changes, an observer would reflect that.

Comment: Essentially yes. But I'd say an observer implies a non-nullable reference, a null pointer wouldn't "observe" much.

Comment: @NeilKirk If "not currently observing" is not a valid state of your object and changing the observed object is  not allowed, then why use a pointer?

Comment: @BaummitAugen I don't know, I just didn't know what it was. What if I want to change the observer to observe something else later?

Comment: @NeilKirk `std::reference_wrapper`